# MQTT-in-iOS - mqttDidDisconnect: Socket closed by remote peer

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt, iot

I have tried implementing mqtt in ios but i am receiving an error in publishing mqttDidDisconnect: "Socket closed by remote peer". Is the problem on the server or on sending the request?

deletegate code

```
func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    print("mqttDidPing")
}

func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    print("mqttDidReceivePong")

}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishAck : \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishComplete id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishComplete: \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didSubscribeTopic: \(topic)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didUnsubscribeTopic: \(topic)")
}

func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
    print("mqttDidDisconnect: \(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
    print("didConnectAck: \(ack)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishMessage: \(message) and \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
    print("didReceiveMessage: \(message) and \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    print("didReceive trust")
}
```

Comment: Do you receive ```func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) ``` first?

Answer (score 0):

You can check my issue https://github.com/emqtt/CocoaMQTT/issues/252. In essence, the problem was server-side related, and the connection was successful using EMQX broker (download from https://github.com/emqx/emqx/releases/download/v3.0.0/emqx-centos7-v3.0.0.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Removing mqtt.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "/will", message: "dieout") solved the issue for me because our user didn't have access to /will topic in ACLs.